# Another word for "hot"(as in feelings)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When you feel something hot in your mouth like pepper: are there any other words for it? Pepperish, perhaps? Is "pepperish" appropriate? Not only in the mouth and any other parts of the body

Comment: Just saying, chief: hot in _feelings_ and hot as a _taste sensation_ are two very, very different things.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for ***[spicy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spicy) or [hot](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-italian/hot)***:

adjective (FOOD)

> - ​containing ​strong ​flavours from ​spices.
> - hot food contains strong spices that cause a burning feeling in your mouth, piccante.
>
>   - The sauce is very hot – be careful!

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

- [Spicy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spicy): flavoured with or fragrant with spice.
- [Piquant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/piquant): having a pleasantly sharp taste or appetizing flavour.
- [Tangy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tangy): having a strong, piquant flavour or smell.
- [***Peppery***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/peppery): strongly flavoured with pepper or other hot spices
- [Picante](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/picante): (of food) spicy.

(Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score 1):

[Pungency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pungency) is a good candidate. As in "It's pungent."

Actually, the entire [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taste#Basic_tastes) article on gustation is pretty intriguing, discussing as it does the basic, as well as some exotic, taste sensations.